# Get field formatter setting value from preprocess

Tags: 7, forms

I have added to media>video files a taxonomy term reference "video_quality", i.e. 480, 720...

I use those files in a content type "video-article" and render the file with `Video.js` module. This module come with some field formatter settings such as "autoplay".

I am building a module for `Video.js` to integrate resolution support. Based on `field_formatter_settings` module, I use `HOOK_field_formatter_settings_form_alter` to alter the formatter settings and add my custom option, i.e. selecting the appropriate taxonomy term reference.

The goal is to alter the Video.js field rendering to add a resolution selector. The resolution is attached to the video file, and the field should obtain this information in the field preprocessing in order to give the various resolutions to the template file.

I don't know how to achieve this in a generic way. I'm able to find the values i'm looking for using the "devel" module:

- vars
- vars > items
- vars > items > [0,1,2]   <-- 3 video files attached to the node in ONE field
- vars > items > 0 > field_quality > und > 0 > taxonomy term ID

The real problem is that I want to get the file's field "field_quality" name without hardcoding it.

How can I request my video field's formatting options to get my custom "resolution_selector" setting (that contains the field name!) ?

#### tl;dr

How can I access field formatter settings from field preprocess? Where are those settings stored?